# using variable inside php query

Tags: php, mysql

hi i want to use different tables in from clause sql query every time in a loop issue is it is not accepting my code here is the code

```
$tbl0="atom_supplier_oe";
$tbl1="atom_supplier_silver_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";
$tbl2="atom_supplier_black_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";
$tbl3="atom_supplier_just_crossed_drilled";
$tbl4="atom_supplier_just_slotted";
$tbl5="atom_supplier_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $sql="select * from $tbl'+$i' where client_id='$id'";
    if(!$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)){

    echo mysql_error($db);
}

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0){
    break;
    //echo mysqli_error($db);
}
```

what is the issue ? i want to use different table for every iteration for comparison.thanks in advance

Comment: PHP strings don't work like that. If you want to iterate over a series of values, put them in an array and use `foreach`.

Comment: You better use a String Array for the table names and interate trough that array

Comment: `$sql="select * from ".$tbl."".$i." where client_id='$id'";

 Please use this query i have concatenated variables correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this. Table names in an array, foreach over that array and process the results accordingly.

```
$id = '';   // not sure where you are getting this from
$db = '';   // again this was not in your example above

$tables = [
    "atom_supplier_oe",
    "atom_supplier_silver_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled",
    "atom_supplier_black_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled",
    "atom_supplier_just_crossed_drilled",
    "atom_supplier_just_slotted",
    "atom_supplier_slotted_and_crossed_drilled",
];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE client_id = %d", $table, $id);

    if (!$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
        echo mysql_error($db);
        continue;
        // or break if you want to still check the other tables.
    }

    // do something with the result here ($result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be help to you.

```
$tbl=array();
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_oe";
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_silver_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_black_coated_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_just_crossed_drilled";
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_just_slotted";
$tbl[]="atom_supplier_slotted_and_crossed_drilled";

for($i=0;$i<count($tbl);$i++){
    $sql="select * from "+$tbl[$i]+" where client_id='$id'";
    if(!$result=mysqli_query($sql,$db)){

    echo mysqli_error($db);
}

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0){
    break;
    //echo mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: nops! stil giving error of Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\atom\leadbox.php on line 223

Comment: I have modified if condition $result=mysqli_query($sql,$db) please check it again

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\atom\leadbox.php on line 222

Comment: which version of php you are using?

Comment: the version of php is 5.5

Comment: Which statement is on line 222?

Comment: Thanks Haresh! i highly appreciate your concern over my issue but its done,keep up the good work.:)

Answer (score 0):

Change following query in the loop.

```
$sql="select * from ".${'tbl'.$i}." where client_id='$id'";
```

This might help you.

Please let me know if you've any queries.

Comment: Use of undefined constant tbl - assumed 'tbl' in C:\xampp\htdocs\atom\leadbox.php on line 222

Answer (score -1):

"select * from $tbl".'$i'."where client_id='$id'"

use dot operator to concatenate